# MarketingCloud MobilePush SDK 6.3.5 dependency cannot be resolved

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android

Our Android project is currently using the 6.3.4 SDK. However when trying to update to the latest version 6.3.5 we get an error:

```
Could not find com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:6.3.5.
Searched in the following locations:
  - http://maven/content/groups/public/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/marketingcloudsdk/6.3.5/marketingcloudsdk-6.3.5.pom
  - http://maven/content/groups/public/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/marketingcloudsdk/6.3.5/marketingcloudsdk-6.3.5.jar
  - http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/repository/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/marketingcloudsdk/6.3.5/marketingcloudsdk-6.3.5.pom
  - http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/repository/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/marketingcloudsdk/6.3.5/marketingcloudsdk-6.3.5.jar
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/marketingcloudsdk/6.3.5/marketingcloudsdk-6.3.5.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/marketingcloudsdk/6.3.5/marketingcloudsdk-6.3.5.jar
```

Is it supposed to be available already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your repo in your dependencies.  See https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html for details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is still same even with updated SalesForce SDK version 8.0.9.

**I got the below solution which is not mentioned in the salesforce documentation also.**

So, instead of add maven url in build.gradle(project)

add it into settings.gradle file like this :

[image]

Hope that this will be helpful to resolve your problem. Best of luck..!!